# Getting error when using Multer to upload to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, multer

I have client side that sends a file to the server:

```js
    public uploadFile(url: string, filePath: string): Promise<ICommandResponse<void>> {
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath));
        return this.instance.post(url, body, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.verify(response.status);
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                throw error(
                    `Failed to upload file from server: ${err?.message}`,
                    { status: err?.response?.status ?? HttpStatus.InternalServerError },
                );
            });
    }
```

In the server, I'm using Multer to upload a file to S3. I validate the user's access token before I upload the file:

```js
    private getUploader(config: IHttpServerConfig) {
        if (!config.s3Bucket) {
            throw error('S3 bucket is not configured', {
                status: HttpStatus.InternalServerError,
            });
        }
        const s3Client = new S3Client({
            region: config.s3Bucket.region,
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: config.s3Bucket.accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: config.s3Bucket.secretAccessKey,
            },
        });
        return this.#uploader ??= multer({
            storage: multerS3({
                s3: s3Client,
                bucket: config.s3Bucket.name,
                contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
                key: (_req, file, cb) => {
                    cb(null, file.originalname);
                },
            }),
            fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
                try {
                    const accessToken = req.cookies[AuthCookieKey.AccessToken];
                    this.authorizeToken(accessToken);
                    return cb(null, true);
                } catch (err) {
                    return cb(err, false);
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

Although I validate the user's access token before uploading the file, it looks like Multer starts to upload the file before the validation and suddenly I'm getting the following error: "Failed to upload file from server: write EPIPE".

Any idea why?

Thanks.